# Matplotlib plots multiple dark lines on x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The following is the plot in question. Dark lines are covering the x-axis, and for some reason it seems I cant debug this. Im trying to chart two columns from a dataframe, the 3 period SMA price against time as can be seen in the code below.

[image: Figure 1]

This is the result of this code

```
import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from binance.client import Client

BASE = "ETH"
QUOTE = "USDT"
MARKET = BASE + QUOTE

client = Client("vitalik",
                "buterin")

klines = client.get_historical_klines(MARKET, Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_15MINUTE, "31 Dec, 2017", "13 Jan, 2018")

# temporary fix

for kline in klines:
    kline[0] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int(kline[0] / 1000)
    ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    kline[6] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int(kline[6] / 1000)
    ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df = pd.DataFrame(klines,
                  columns=["open_time", "open", "high", "low", "close", "volume", "close_time", "quote_asset_volume",
                           "trades", "base_volume", "quote_volume", "ignore"])

df['sma_3'] = df["close"].rolling(window=3).mean()

print(df.dtypes)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.xaxis_date()

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.title(MARKET)
plt.plot_date(x=df["close_time"], y=df["sma_3"], fmt="r-")
plt.show()
```

The result of `print(df.dtypes)` is:

```
open_time              object
open                   object
high                   object
low                    object
close                  object
volume                 object
close_time             object
quote_asset_volume     object
trades                  int64
base_volume            object
quote_volume           object
ignore                 object
sma_5                 float64
sma_3                 float64
dtype: object
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is too many x labels, so need set them to not visible:

```
spacing = 10
visible = ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[::spacing]
for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
    if label not in visible:
        label.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: how this will help in normal x-axis and y-axis array? I think This hack is specific to the above code. Will you please tell other than this to solve this problem

Comment: @babygame0ver - I think yes, only change `spacing` to small number like `2`.

Comment: I am using get_ticklabels() fxn on the x-axis list but it is saying AttribueError as list doesn't support any fxn. So what to do now ?

Comment: @babygame0ver - What return `print (ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels())` ?

Comment: I am not using the fxn subplot as used in the above code. I have an x-axis list and y-axis list about 2000 values in both. When I am plotting them it is causing the same trouble as the above pic. BTW x-axis value range from 1-2000 and y-axis from 0.1 - 0.9 SO you can get the idea.

Comment: @babygame0ver - Hmmm, not idea. Maybe the best is create new question.

Answer (score 2):

You are using strings as the quantity to plot on the x axis. Hence each point will get its own label. The accumulation of all those labels looks like "dark lines".

In order to have the correct labeling you need to use datetime objects to plot, not strings.

I cannot test because I do not have `binance` available, but the easiest option might be to just remove the `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` part in the data generation.